Orthogonal Projection in an Enlarged Hilbert Space
Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_H)$ and $(U,\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_U )$ be Hilbert Spaces such that $H$ embeds into $U$. Let $M$ be a closed subspace of $U$, and define $\mathcal{P}$ to be the orthogonal projection in $U$ onto $M$. Assume in addition that $M$ is a closed subspace of $H$, and that the restriction of $\mathcal{P}$ to $H$ is the orthogonal projection in $H$ onto $M$ (of course it is a projection onto $M$, but we assume it is the orthogonal projection, that is it is self-adjoint in $H$).
Now suppose that there exists an enlargement of $H$, a new Hilbert Space $(\bar{H}, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_H)$ with again the $H$ inner product, and the property that $H \subset \bar{H} \subset U$. Now $M$ is again a closed subspace of $\bar{H}$, so I can define the orthogonal projection $\bar{\mathcal{P}}$ in $\bar{H}$ onto $M$.
My question is, is the restriction of $\mathcal{P}$ to $\bar{H}$ equal to $\bar{\mathcal{P}}$? It is sufficient to show that $\mathcal{P}$ is self-adjoint in $\bar{H}$, and although it is self-adjoint in $H$, and $\bar{H}$ has the same inner product, I am unsure if the self-adjoint property holds in the larger space. I have tried to decompose $\bar{H}$ as the direct sum of $H$ and its complement, knowing I have the self-adjoint property on $H$, but without information on the complement I am unsure.
Any help would be appreciated, many thanks!

No. Let $U=\tilde H = \mathbb R^2$. Let the inner product on $U$ be the canonical inner product of $\mathbb R^2$, while the inner product of $\tilde H$ is induced by $\pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 2 & 5}$.
Define $H:= \{ x\in \mathbb R^2: \ x_2=0\}$ with inner product $\langle x,y\rangle_H = x_1y_1$. Then the inner product of $H$ coincides with the restriction of the inner products of $U$ and $\tilde H$.
Let $P=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$ the projection in $U=\mathbb R^2$ onto $H$.
Then $P$ is not self-adjoint in $\tilde H$.

Great illustrative example, many thanks!
